# Unable to run QuickCheck for Haskell after updating macOS to Monterey

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, quickcheck

After updating the OS, I have updated the command line tools as well and have tried reinstalling QuickCheck using cabal which shows something like "resolving dependencies". Now every time I try running the folder containing the Haskell, I get the following error:

```
Ambiguous module name ‘Test.QuickCheck’:
      it was found in multiple packages:
      QuickCheck-2.14.2 QuickCheck-2.14.2
```

[image]

Comment: Check the file `/Users/arneshsaha/.ghc/aarch64-darwin-8.10.7/env
ironments/default`. You'll most likely see two entries there for `QuickCheck`. Remove the first one you see.

Comment: Please do not use pictures, they diminish accessibility. Cut and paste code and errors.